# Why is it important to add 'Experimental' annotation?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

What is the benefit of adding annotations suggested by the lint such as "@ExperimentalApi" or other recommended stuff like this?

Does it mean in the future it can warn us if the API changed?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it means that the API can change or be removed in future.

Experimental APIs are good for testing around new functionalities but usually their use is discouraged in production code.

PS: Kotlin now uses `@RequiresOptIn` (and `@OptIn`) instead of `@Experimental` which is deprecated. You can find more info [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/opt-in-requirements.html)

Comment: Thansk for your answer. I was aware of the meaning but I am still wondering what is the actuel benefit of adding the annotation to the code? Just a reminder for yourself when you comeback to this codebase that it can break sometimes in the futur?
Or is there something more?

Comment: @CyrilNiobé have a look at the link in the answer - because the APIs can change, users have to *explicitly* opt-in to using them, and these annotations are the way you do that. (Or you can opt-in to every experimental API used in a module instead of annotating everything.) There are two different annotations too - `@RequiresOptIn` consents to using an experimental API, and any of your client code that references that API will *also* require opt-in (the requirement gets propagated down the chain). Adding `@OptIn` to your client code allows it to consent and remove that requirement from callers

Comment: @CyrilNiobé The actual benefit is to inform the developer to try to avoid that API in production code, it is like a warning